# Creating a search box for the Google sheet data using Angular JS?

Tags: html, angularjs, google-sheets-api

// I was able to do search among the static array of data. I want to do the search in google sheet data.

//  I have published my Google sheet data as a json and tried to extrack the data and input to the $.scope. Since I'm new to the Angular js I'm not able to fix this. Could you help in fixing below code.

```
<html>
           <head>

            input {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            font-size: 12px;
            height: 30px;
            padding: 4px 8px;
            position: absolute;
            width: 50%;
           }
           input:focus {
            outline: none;
            }

        button {
           text-align: center;
          }
        button:focus {
         outline: none;
        }
           button.btn-search, button.btn-reset {
           background: #568683;
           border: none;
           height: 30px;
           font-size: 12px;
           padding: 4px;
           position: absolute;
           width: 30px;
           }

          .sample {
           float: left;
           height: 50px;
           margin: 0 8%;
           position: relative;
           width: 34%;
           }
           .sample.ten input {
           border-radius: 15px;
           transition: all .6s ease-in-out .3s;
           width: 120px;
            }
          .sample.ten input:focus {
           transition-delay: 0;
           width: 200px;
           }
          .sample.ten input:focus ~ button {
           transform: rotateZ(360deg);
          }
          .sample.ten input:focus ~ button.btn-search {
          background: #568683;
          color: #fff;
          left: 172px;
          transition-delay: 0;
          }
          .sample.ten input:focus ~ button.btn-reset {
           left: 202px;
           transition-delay: .3s;
           }
           .sample.ten button {
             transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
            }
           .sample.ten button.btn-search {
             background: #ccc;
             border-radius: 50%;
             height: 26px;
             left: 92px;
             top: 2px;
             transition-delay: .3s;
             width: 26px;
              }
             .sample.ten button.btn-reset {
               background: #fff;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
               border-radius: 50%;
                 font-size: 10px;
              height: 20px;
               left: 92px;
                 line-height: 20px;
                    padding: 0;
                  top: 5px;
                    width: 20px;
                 z-index: -1;
                 }
        </style>



                   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular.min.js"> 
      </script>

                 <script>


                        // Json file : https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/1OJX_UfZ7KQ- 
                    NMKcpXmYT8Ml1OfzerPnmUyEcSoMqeZc/public/basic?alt=json
                  angular.module('sample', []).controller('sampleController',function($scope, $http) {
                  $http("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/1OJX_UfZ7KQ- 
          NMKcpXmYT8Ml1OfzerPnmUyEcSoMqeZc/public/basic?alt=json")
          .success(function(response) {$scope.users = response.data;
                             });

        });


                 </script>
                 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular-route.js"> 
          </script>
         </head>
           <body>
           <div ng-app="sample" >

            <input type="text" name="search" ng-model="search.$" placeholder="search">

            <br>
            <br>
           <br>
           <table ng-controller="sampleController" style="border: 1px solid black ;">
             <tbody>

           <tr class="users" ng-repeat="user in users | filter:search">

              <td  style="border: 1px solid black ;">{{user}}</td>
             </tr>
              </tbody>
             </table>
            </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Please provide some sample code showing what you have tried to do already and what problems you have run into. That will allow us to better help you.

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks I have added my code to the question body. Please help!

Comment: Hi Tom, I have added my sample code to the question body, please have a look.